# How can I capture the data from a component input?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, formkit

I have a component call NewIngredientInput, that I use on my newrecipe page. The component is made up of 3 inputs ***amount***, ***unit*** and ***name***. I'm using Nuxt 3, handling the forms with Formkit and consuming and external API.

When I send the data from the form to the endpoint for posting, its only capturing the information from the input ***amount***, for the other two inputs (***unit*** and ***name***) it sends an empty string so the POST request succeeds. I specify that for the other inputs that are not inside the NewIngredientInput component, the information is successfully captured.

Here is my code for newrecipe page:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <UserMenu />
    <SideNavUser />
    <div class="new-recipe-container">
      <div class="title">Crear Receta</div>
      <div class="form">
        <FormKit type="form" @submit="createRecipe">
          <FormKit
            v-model="recipeData.name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            label="Título de la Receta"
            validation="required"
          />
          <div
            class="new-ingredient"
            v-for="(row, index) in inputRows"
            :key="index"
          >
            <NewIngredientInput
              v-model="row.amount"
              v-model:unit_measure="row.unit_measure"
              v-model:name="row.name"
              :showRemoveButton="index > 0"
              @removeRow="removeRow(index)"
            />
            <button @click="addRow" class="add">+</button>
          </div>
          <FormKit
            v-model="recipeData.description"
            type="textarea"
            rows="10"
            name="description"
            label="Instrucciones"
            placeholder="Escribe oraciones o párrafos."
            validation="required"
          />
          <div class="triple">
            <FormKit
              v-model="recipeData.region"
              type="text"
              name="region"
              label="Región"
              validation="required"
            />
            <FormKit
              v-model="recipeData.keywords"
              type="text"
              name="keywords"
              label="Palabras Clave"
              placeholder="pollo, ajo, ..."
              help="Ingresa palabras claves separadas por comas."
              validation="required"
            />
            <div class="photo">
              <FormKit
                type="file"
                name="photo"
                accept=".jpg,.png"
                label="Imagen"
                help="Solo puedes incluir imagenes con extensión .jpg o .png"
                validation="required"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <FormKit type="submit" label="Crear" />
        </FormKit>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NewIngredientInput from "../components/NewIngredientInput.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {
    NewIngredientInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputRows: [{ amount: "", unit_measure: "", name: "" }],
      recipeData: {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        region: "",
        keywords: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputRows.push({ amount: "", unit_measure: "", name: "" });
    },
    removeRow(index) {
      this.inputRows.splice(index, 1);
    },

    async createRecipe() {
      try {
        const photoInput = document.querySelector('input[name="photo"]');

        if (photoInput && photoInput.files && photoInput.files.length > 0) {
          const photoForm = new FormData();
          photoForm.append("photo", photoInput.files[0]);

          const imageResponse = await axios.post(
            "API endpoint for upload newImage",
            photoForm,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${photoForm._boundary}`,
              },
            }
          );

          const ingredient = this.inputRows.map((row) => {
            return {
              amount: row.amount.amount,
              unit: row.unit_measure,
              name: row.name,
            };
          });

          const recipeForm = {
            name: this.recipeData.name,
            ingredients: ingredient,
            description: this.recipeData.description,
            region: this.recipeData.region,
            keywords: this.recipeData.keywords,
            photo: imageResponse.data,
          };

          console.log(recipeForm);

          const recipeResponse = await axios.post(
            "API endpoint for upload the entire recipe",
            recipeForm
          );

          console.log("Receta creada exitosamente: ", recipeResponse.data);
        } else {
          console.error("No se seleccionó ninguna imagen");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If I don't use `v-model:unit_measure="row.unit_measure"` and `v-model:name="row.name"` on NewIngredientInput, when I add a row for a new ingredient it inherits the information from the old one and is overwritten, resulting in a single row instead of an array with several ingredients.

I also attached the script of the NewIngredientInput component for more context:

```
<template>
  <FormKit type="form" name="ingredients">
    <div class="newIngredient">
      <FormKit
        v-model="ingredient.amount"
        type="number"
        name="amount"
        id="amount"
        label="Cantidad"
        min="1"
        validation="required"
      />
      <FormKit
        v-model="ingredient.unit_measure"
        type="text"
        name="unit"
        id="unit"
        label="Unidad"
        validation="required"
      />
      <div class="ingredient">
        <FormKit
          v-model="ingredient.name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          label="Ingrediente"
          validation="required"
        />
      </div>
      <button class="remove" @click="removeRow" v-show="showRemoveButton">
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  </FormKit>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    showRemoveButton: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    // Pass the ingredient object as a prop
    ingredientValue: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ingredient: { amount: "", unit_measure: "", name: "" },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    // When the prop value (ingredient object) changes, update the local ingredient data
    ingredientValue: {
      handler(newValue) {
        this.ingredient.amount = newValue.amount;
        this.ingredient.unit_measure = newValue.unit_measure;
        this.ingredient.name = newValue.name;
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    removeRow() {
      this.$emit("removeRow");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar. What you posted so far is not enough to create a runnable example, which means no potential answer could be tested. One thing I noticed in what you posted so far and you probably shouldn't be doing is nesting forms. It looks like `<NewIngredientInput />` has a form element and you're placing it in another form element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the problem is how you're using v-model on your NewIngredientInput component. It should bind to a single model, but you're binding to multiple models (amount, unit_measure, name). Here is the simplified solution:

Change your `NewIngredientInput` in `newrecipe` page like this:

```
<NewIngredientInput
  :value="row"
  :showRemoveButton="index > 0"
  @removeRow="removeRow(index)"
/>
```

And:

```
<template>
  <!-- Your existing template code -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    showRemoveButton: Boolean,
    value: { type: Object, required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return { ingredient: { ...this.value } };
  },
  watch: {
    ingredient: {
      handler() { this.$emit('update', this.ingredient); },
      deep: true
    },
    value: {
      handler(newValue) { this.ingredient = { ...newValue }; },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeRow() { this.$emit("removeRow"); },
  },
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps!